# Asp.net core adding Controller using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model with some attributes and I am creating a new controller based on that model using entity framework but it throws me a error as: `There is no entity type EnquiryModel on DbContext ProjectName.Data.ApplicationDbContext`. 
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V1mi.png)

I also tried to add my model to the application's `DbContext` using :

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<EnquiryModel> EnquiryModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

I've rebuilt the solution, but it still give me the same error.

Any solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried public DbSet<EnquiryModel> EnquiryModel { get; set; } ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that to put that in application.Dbcontext (written in the brief as well).

Comment: It's not the same, in your question you aren't using genercis for DbSet, can you post your DbContext code ?

Comment: namespace Project.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options) 
        {
        }
        public DbSet<EnquiryModel> EnquiryModel { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}

Comment: It seems like you don't have key for your entity, you can set key and other configurations inside of OnModelCreating method

Answer (score 0):

Modify your DbContext with this:

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<EnquiryModel> EnquiryModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // I'm assuming you have a property with name EnquiryID
            builder.Entity<EnquiryModel>().HasKey(p => p.EnquiryID);

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to define a key for your entity.

Let me know if this is useful.

Comment: It is still same. I have added a Key in my model and used your code above but it is still same.

Comment: Code for adding my key:
     [Key] public int ID { get; set; }